# Creating an object of xml layout

Tags: android, xml, object, view

I want to add a view to my activity by creating an instance of of a view object so suppose this is my activity

```
public class ConverTo extends FragmentActivity

private LinearLayout l1;
private LengthFragment test;

private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //methods to call on app launch 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.converto_home);  


    pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById (R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter (pagerAdapter);
    test = new LengthFragment(ConverTo.this);

     l1 = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_temperature, null);
    addView(l1);
```

when I do this ^^ it displays the view properly. Instead of doing this ^^ 
I would like to do this

```
 LengthFragment l1= new LengthFragment(context,getLayoutInflater());
 addView(l1);
```

and my lengthfragment class will associate itself to an xml file.

```
public class LengthFragment extends View implements OnClickListener,     OnItemSelectedListener{


public LengthFragment(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater){
    super(context);
    rContext = context;
inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_length, null, false);
```

I have tried doing this ^^, all it gives me is an empty view.

Answer (score 0):

For this line,

```
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_length, container, false);
```

What is container?  It should be the desired parent of your new view.  Try setting the last parameter to true (attachToRoot).

Comment: That was typo. container is null and attach to root didn't help